# Attribute array?

Tags: c++, arrays, console

I am making a console rpg in c++, and I have a question. Can I make an array that will store character's attributes, which will be changed like this "`Attribute [atr_health] += 200;`" (I have this idea from a game where attributes are changed like this "`hero.attribute[ATR_HITPOINTS] += 1;`") ? And will this code work "`Attribute [atr_health] -= damage;`"?

Comment: What about a class for characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `map` or an `unordered_map` and an `enum` for accesing its values:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

enum Attrs {DAMAGE, LIFE, ARMOUR};


class Dude
{
    private:
     map<int, int> attrs;
    //You can use a string map instead
    //map<string, int> attrs;
    public:
    Dude()
    {
        attrs[DAMAGE]   = 10;
        //attrs["DAMAGE"]   = 10;
        attrs[LIFE]     = 10;
        //attrs["LIFE"]     = 10;
        attrs[ARMOUR]   = 5;
        //attrs["ARMOUR"]   = 10;
    }
}
```

Something like this might work.

Comment: `map<Attrs, int> attrs;`, not `map<int, int> attrs;`... Also, since that `enum` has meaning only inside class `Dude`, you should move it in the public part of the class.

Comment: An array would be simpler and more efficient, if the keys are a simple set of contiguous zero-based integers like this. Use maps if you need support for more complicated key types.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo, you are true on the map stuff, but I think that having the enum private its not wornt at all, maybe he will need to use it in other parts of the maingame code.

Comment: @DanielSanchez in fact, I said "public", not "private" :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour, yes it will be more efficient, this is just my opinion. I've use the map for games, having access with strings is helpful when you try to load stuff from files. Just my opion too anyway :)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo, ups, yes, I just messed it. Fully true then :)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about classes / structs.

Classes are a clean way to bundle various related values together in a single object and provide an abstracted access to these values.

An example how this could look in your case:

```
enum class Attribute
{
   Health, Dexterity
}

class Character
{
    std::map<Attribute, unsigned int> attributes;

public:

   unsigned int GetAttribute(Attribute type) { return attributes[type]; }

   unsigned int GetHealth() { return GetAttribute(Attribute::Health); }
   unsigned int GetDexterity() { return GetAttribute(Attribute::Dexterity); }
}
```

As you can see I introduced several constructs here:

- An `enum class` is a strongly typed enum
- A `std::map` holds values for distinct keys, it basically maps `key` to `value`
- Getter methods abstract the access to the underlying data structur, in this case we have one generic method and multiple concrete methods.

You could use the `Character` class like this:

```
Character myCharacter;

unsigned int health = myCharacter.GetHealth(); // usign the concrete getter
unsigned int dexterity = myCharacter.GetAttribute(Attribute::Dexterity); // using the generic getter
```

In the example I only implemented getters, a setter could look like this:

```
void SetAttribute(Attribute type, unsigned int value)
{
    attributes[type] = value;
}
```

A more advanced implementation, could abstract these set of values (attributes) in a `Attributes` class (in this case we just need to rename our class, as it does not hold any character related informations than attributes). The advantage of this approach is, that the class can be reused e.g for weapons having attribute boni. The drawback is a slightly more verbous access.